# Tree view dragdrop before drop handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ext.net

i am trying to perform drag and drop event in tree panel with some restriction. 
I have two tree view and i need to drag the content of right tree to left tree with some restriction.
1)I need to check whether the dragged item is on left tree or not. If yes do not allow the task to complete
2)If the dragged item has children then notification should be shown about the node having children nodes. if user clicks yes it should allow all the nodes to be copied and if not it should allow only parent node

I have written the code in javascript as follows(Note i am using razor for user interface)

```
function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropFunction) {

var record = data.records[0].data;

var nodeElem = data.item;
//before dropping item to the destination tree view we have to check if the item already exists

var exists = (nodeElem.find('.completed').length > 0);
if(exists)
{
    return false;
}
    //validate hierarchy level and parent node
var target = overModel;
//target.parentNode.data.id
var depth=target.getDepth();


if ( depth > 1) {
    if (target.data.id != record.parentId) {
        return false;
    }
}
//check for existing nodes
var destTree = Ext.getCmp('tpDestination');
var found = findChildNodes(record.id, destTree);//dind childnodes checks the presence of chiild node
if (found) {
    Ext.Msg.alert({
        title: 'Alert',
        msg: "The destination tree contains one of it's child domain. Please remove it's children and retry.",
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
    });
    return false;
}
//allow copy of nodes. it overrides the move functionality
data.copy = true;
//show the confirmation message, if the node has children.
var isLeaf = record.leaf;
if (!isLeaf) {
    //wait until confirmation complete
    dropFunction.wait = true;
    Ext.Msg.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm',
        msg: "Do you want to copy children also?",
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
        fn: function (btn) {
            if (btn == 'no') {
                data.copyChildren = false;
            }
            dropFunction.processDrop();
        }
    });
}

data.dropNode = data.records[0];

return true; };
```

completed is the node class of the right panel and the code is supposed to check whether the dragged element has the class completed is present but it is not working and i have no clue
when user clicks no it still add all the nodes along the child node

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related discussion on the Ext.NET forums:
http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?24387